# Meaning of the word 'rap'

Tags: meaning

> CIA takes *rap* for embassy attack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rap?show=0&t=1297522254):

> the responsibility for or adverse consequences of an action: *refused to take the rap*.

The CIA took the responsibility for allowing the embassy attack.

Comment: Is it a metaphor?

Answer (score 6):

While I agree with @Kosmonaut, I think it may be useful to advert to the derivation of this word. From [Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=rap&searchmode=none):

> "quick, light blow," mid-14c., native or borrowed from a Scandinavian source (cf. Dan. rap, Swed. rapp "light blow"); either way probably of imitative origin (cf. slap, clap). The verb is attested from late 14c. **Slang noun meaning "rebuke, blame, responsibility" is from 1777**; specific meaning "criminal indictment" (cf. rap sheet, 1960) is from 1903. To rap (someone's) knuckles "give light punishment" is from 1749.

So this stems from the meaning of *rap* as "a blow" (in the sense of striking someone with the hand) and acquired the additional meaning of "punishment" along the way and then added to that a sense of criminal culpability.

Comment: @lovespring: Aww, you teased me.

Comment: **tease** means 'Make fun of or attempt to provoke (a person or animal) in a playful way'. Trust me, in my whole life till now, I never use this words. Is it a joke ? :)

Comment: @lovespring: I happened to log on and find you had accepted my answer. Ten seconds when I went to the questions I noticed you had taken the acceptance away from me and given it to someone else. So in the sense I used it, it means "to tempt someone with something without actually providing that thing." (In short, I was just joking with you.)

Comment: It's hard to choose, first right v.s. best in detail. I choose the former, and many people have up-vote you.

Answer (score 1):

The NOAD reports that *to take the rap* is used in informal contexts for *be punished or blamed, especially for something that is not one's fault or for which others are equally responsible*.

Notice also that *rap* is an informal word used for *criminal charge*, or *a person or thing's reputation*.

Answer (score 0):

Literally, *rap* means *knock*! A reprimand or rebuke now considered old-fashioned by some, a knock on the head—quick, instant and effective—was the favorite of parents and disciplinarians who did not shy away from corporal punishment.

Answer (score 0):

*A rap on the knuckles* is a commonly used idiom, synonymous with *a slap on the wrist*.